# Why does CSS animation through javascript only happen once

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on making a Navigation Bar, because it is entertaining, but when trying to make a slight fade on hover using animations, for some reason the javascript implemented hoverout is only working once, and then it never does it again until refreshed.

Why is that, and are there any alternatives to doing this in javascript.

```js
let navChildren = [...document.getElementById('nav-container').children]

navChildren.forEach(x => {
    x.addEventListener('click', () => {
        
    })
    x.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        x.style.animation = 'hoverOut 1s forwards'
    })
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  animation: hoverIn 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes hoverIn {
    0% { background-color: #333; }
    100% { background-color: #111; }
}

@keyframes hoverOut {
    0% { background-color: #111; }
    100% { background-color: #333; }
}

.active { background-color: #222; }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <ul id = 'nav-container'>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the animation, then set it back to reset it:

```js
let navChildren = [...document.getElementById('nav-container').children]

navChildren.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', () => {

  })
  x.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    x.style.animation = "none";
    setTimeout(function() {
      x.style.animation = 'hoverOut 1s forwards'
    }, 0)
  })
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  animation: hoverIn 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes hoverIn {
  0% {
    background-color: #333;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #111;
  }
}

@keyframes hoverOut {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #333;
  }
}

.active {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul id='nav-container'>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Although an easier way is just to use CSS transitions, no JavaScript required:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

@keyframes hoverOut {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #333;
  }
}

.active {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul id='nav-container'>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, and is there any better way to go about this, say in CSS, or just in Javascript in general

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent I've updated my answer to show you a simpler way.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `animationend` event listener to refresh the animation.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#using_animation_events

```js
let navChildren = [...document.getElementById('nav-container').children]

navChildren.forEach(x => {
  
    x.addEventListener("animationend",()=>x.style.animation = "none");

    x.addEventListener('mouseout',()=>x.style.animation = 'hoverOut 1s forwards');
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  animation: hoverIn 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes hoverIn {
    0% { background-color: #333; }
    100% { background-color: #111; }
}

@keyframes hoverOut {
    0% { background-color: #111; }
    100% { background-color: #333; }
}

.active { background-color: #222; }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <ul id = 'nav-container'>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```